# java which approach is the best?

Tags: java, collections

**Requirement**

1. With a given `Map<String, String>`
2. percent encode each key/value entry
3. sort entries by encoded keys
4. append them as a single string like `?a=b&c=d`

**Approach 1**

1. Prepare a `TreeMap`.
2. Put those encoded key/value entries to this map.
3. Concatenate the output string while iterating the map.

**Approach 2**

1. Prepare an `ArrayList` with predicted size (source-map.size *2)
2. Insert those encode key/values while finding the right position
3. Concatenate the output string while iterating the list

**Approach 3**

1. Prepare a `LinkedList`
2. Insert those encode key/values while finding the right position
3. Concatenate the output string while iterating the list

Which approach is the best?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asymptotic complexity with n being the number of key-value pairs:

Approach 1: O(n log n)

Approach 2: O(n^2)

Approach 3: O(n^2)

The first approach will be faster than the others for reasonably big n but the others may be faster when there are very few keys.